# how to open an image file from root folder (/data/local/2.jpg) in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I am using `linux` and installed `android-sdk`.

I have created a `android emulator`. It works nicely. I could install whatsapp and it works.

using adb i have push a jpg file in the `/data/local/` folder.

in the `adb shell` when i do `ls`, it shows the jpg file.

How to view my file in the gallery of my adroid emulator. I have installed an app called `andexplorer`. It shows the data folder in the root directory but when i enter the data folder nothing is shown. In the data folder there is local and many other folders and files.

Since android is using linux. I found in the terminal emulator in the dev tools. Can i view an image by some command like `#display /data/local/2.jpg` or which is the command for image viewer

Answer (score 0):

/data/local/ is not readable / accessible from regular Android applications (only the 'shell' and 'root' users can, which is why the file appears in with 'adb shell ls').

You need to copy the file to a world-readable location, like /sdcard instead.